# Reading files in java line by line getting an exception after last line

Tags: java, file

I'm getting an issue where after I read the last line I'm getting a no such element exception and I was wondering how can I go about modifying the while loop to avoid this?

```
File file = new File(fileName); 
Scanner fileInput;
String line;
try {
     fileInput = new Scanner(file);
     while ( (line = fileInput.nextLine() ) != null  ) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
     fileInput.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Oh and then assign it to my string. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That's not how you should be using a Scanner, and you're confusing how you'd use a BufferedReader with how you'd use a Scanner.  The while should instead check for `Scanner#hasNextLine()`

```
while (fileInput.hasNextLine()) {
   line = fileInput.nextLine();
   // use line here
}
```

or you could use try-with-resources, something like:

```
File file = new File(fileName); 
String line = "";

// use try-with resources
try (Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(file) {
    while (fileInput.hasNextLine() ) {
        line = fileInput.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
// no need to close Scanner/File as the try-with-resources does this for you
```